# SD Adapter for Micro-SD not showing in the Disks and Devices popup or the media folder in Root

Tags: kubuntu, sd-card

I have a Sandisk SD Adapter that supports MicroSD, MicroSDHC, MicroSDXC, and I have a Team brand 8GB MicroSDHC in it. When I plug it in it is not showing in my disks and devices list, but I hear the computer making some noise like something happened. I can not find the SD card in my Media folder.